# Swift: How to write a variant of enumerate that takes an optional sequence type

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I tried to add an override for enumerate that handles the case of an optional sequence (without crashing).  The idea was that if the sequence is valid aka .Some, it would enumerate that sequence, otherwise enumerate an empty sequence:

```
func enumerate2<Seq : SequenceType>(base: Seq?) -> EnumerateSequence<Seq> {
    // if optional sequence is specified
    if let b = base { return enumerate(b) }

    // enumerate empty sequence
    let a = Array<Seq.Generator.Element>()
    return Swift.enumerate(a)
}

func enumerate3<Seq : SequenceType, T where T == Seq.Generator.Element>(base: Seq?) -> EnumerateSequence<Seq> {
    // if optional sequence is specified
    if let b = base { return enumerate(b) }

    // enumerate empty sequence
    let a = Array<T>()
    return Swift.enumerate(a)
}
```

I am seeing the error:

`'Array<Seq.Generator.Element>' does not conform to protocol 'GeneratorType'`

on the last return lines: `return Swift.enumerate(a)`

This confuses me as `EnumerateSequence<Seq>` does not appear to conform to `GeneratorType`.  This seems like a simple enough exercise, what could I be missing?

Note that the above code is split apart for illustration, and the suffixes 2 and 3 are to keep remove ambiguity.

## Edit:

One work around is to return an Optional sequence instead of an empty sequence.

```
func enumerate<Seq : SequenceType>(base: Seq?) -> EnumerateSequence<Seq>? {
    return base != nil  ? enumerate(base) : nil
}
```

The problem then shifts to safely enumerating optionals:

```
public func each<S:SequenceType, T where T == S.Generator.Element>
    (seq: S, with fn:(T)->()) {
        for s in seq { fn(s) }
}

public func each<S:SequenceType, T where T == S.Generator.Element>
    (seq: S?, with fn:(T)->()) {
        if let some = seq {
            for s in some { fn(s) }
        }
}


let es = enumerate(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
each(es) { p in
    println("\(p.0), \(p.1)")
}

let b:[Int]? = nil
let nes = enumerate(b)
each(nes) { p in
    println("\(p.0), \(p.1)")
}

println("done")
```

which produces:

```
0, a
1, b
2, c
3, d
done
```

Perhaps though, the explicit use of if let... is better just for being more obvious, but I am still curious about the initial compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a good solution to this posted on [dev forurms](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1070619#1070619).

The solution requires altering the return type and and using SequenceOf(EmptyCollection>(...)), but that does not appear to have any negative impact since the compiler will already differentiate based on the optional argument type.  The code is:

```
func enumerate<Seq: SequenceType>(base: Seq?) -> SequenceOf<(Int, Seq.Generator.Element)> {
  if let base = base {
    return SequenceOf(Swift.enumerate(base))
  } else {
    return SequenceOf(EmptyCollection<(Int, Seq.Generator.Element)>())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because your function declaration says you're returning an `EnumerateSequence<Seq>`, but that last line would return a `EnumerateSequence <Array<Seq.Generator.Element>>`—those aren't the same, so the compiler won't allow it.

You need to be able to create an empty instance of `Seq` type, but the `SequenceType` protocol doesn't specify an initializer - you need to go down the chain to `ExtensibleCollectionType` to find a protocol with an initializer, so change your generic constraint to that. Then you can do this:

```
func enumerate3<Seq : ExtensibleCollectionType>(base: Seq?) -> EnumerateSequence<Seq> {
    // if optional sequence is specified
    if let b = base { return enumerate(b) }

    // enumerate empty sequence
    let a = Seq()
    return enumerate(a)
}
```

*Note:* if you look through the Swift headers, it won't show you that `Array` conforms to `ExtensibleCollectionProtocol`, but it actually does through a "hidden" `ArrayType` protocol.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around this.  I thought I created a higher level sequence (Array) of the same underlying sequence type (Seq.Generator.Element) of the incoming and return types.  Since an Array is also a SequenceType<Seq.Generator.Element>, which is my advertised return type, this seems like it should have worked.  Is Swift so picky that the two are not equivalent by derivation / base protocols?  It feels like I am declaring I will return type A, and am instead returning type B, which is derived from A - which I thought should work. What I am still missing?  (thanks)

Comment: What if instead of passing in an `Array<T>` I pass in a `Slice<T>`? Your function declaration promises that you're returning an `EnumeratorSequence` wrapped around the *same type* that was passed in.